# How to Categorize a Pie Chart using PHP and MySql

Tags: php, sql, database, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am trying to categorize expenses using a pie chart and php. However, every time I input an expense it shows up as another category.

For example, if there are two expenses made under the *Entertainment* category, there would be two separate sections on the Pie chart, each one representing one expense.

However, I would like to group all expenses with the same category together.

The following is my script used to generate the pie chart. Thank you!

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

      <?php

      $result1=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Housing' and user_id='$id'");
      while($row1=$result1->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Housing'," .$row1['amount']."],";
      }

      $result2=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Transportation' and user_id='$id'");
      while($row2=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Transportation'," .$row2['amount']."],";
      }

      $result3=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Food' and user_id='$id'");
      while($row3=$result3->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Food'," .$row3['amount']."],";
      }

      $result4=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Utilities' and user_id='$id'");
      while($row4=$result4->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Utilities'," .$row4['amount']."],";
      }

      $result5=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Medical/Healthcare'");
      while($row5=$result5->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Medical/Healthcare'," .$row5['amount']."],";
      }

      $result6=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Personal'");
      while($row6=$result6->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Personal'," .$row6['amount']."],";
      }

      $result7=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Education'");
      while($row7=$result7->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Education'," .$row7['amount']."],";
      }

      $result8=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Gifts/Donations'");
      while($row8=$result8->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Gifts/Donations'," .$row8['amount']."],";
      }

      $result9=$con->query("select amount from info where category='Entertainment'");
      while($row9=$result9->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['Entertainment'," .$row9['amount']."],";
      }
       ?>
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is an error in the comparison operator `=` used in `while`.

Or you could simply use a `foreach` loop?:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    ...
}
```